# Detect when UISlider begins and ends dragging

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uislider

In Xamarin iOS, how does one detect when a `UISlider` begins dragging and ends dragging? I want to take certain kinds of actions upon each event, but I'm not sure how to receive these notifications. I looked at the `ValueChanged` event, but this gets triggered only when the value has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with the UIControl's [Touch Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uicontrol.touchdown?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UISlider slider = new UISlider();
    this.Add(slider);

    slider.TouchDragEnter += (o, s) => {
        Console.WriteLine("slider touched");
    };

    slider.TouchDragExit += (o, s) => {
        Console.WriteLine("touch exit");
    };

    slider.TouchUpInside += (o, s) => {
        Console.WriteLine("button touched");
    };

    slider.TouchUpOutside += (o, s) => {
        Console.WriteLine("touch exit");
    };
}
```